# centos 6.7 - no connection- unknown host

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm new to centos.

When I'm at work I'm able to connect to my centos server from my mac, Now I'm trying to connect from home and I can't.

I've tried pinging google.com and recieved: unknown host google.com .

Maybe it's something with the ip I get from my home router?

here's my /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Here's my ifconfig:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:42:B3:AC:2C
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:42ff:feb3:ac2c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:730172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:582258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:642394306 (612.6 MiB)  TX bytes:59636955 (56.8 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:42:19:FB:DC
          inet addr:10.37.129.3  Bcast:10.37.129.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdb2:2c26:f4e4:1:21c:42ff:fe19:fbdc/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:42ff:fe19:fbdc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:694184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:465777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:104085044 (99.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1662635867 (1.5 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3581071 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3581071 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3060357993 (2.8 GiB)  TX bytes:3060357993 (2.8 GiB)

P.S-

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using Nginx server. I can't restart it also.

Answer (score 0):

Please checks your Centos server file

```
/etc/hosts.allow
```

It maybe only allowing certain IPs access to the Centos Box
Your work IP maybe in there but your home IP may not